# "begin transaction" yields error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-7

The entirety of my code is:

```
BEGIN TRAN --SACTION
SELECT 1
COMMIT --TRAN
```

with any combination of `tran`, `transaction` or neither it always returns error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 7.0. This is a corporate system, a legacy. I can't update it from my own accord.

The code does nothing useful but demonstrates the problem. `commit` or `commit transaction` yields the same error. No [mimic](https://github.com/reinderien/mimic), I wrote the code myself.

Trying `BEGIN TRAN SELECT 1 COMMIT TRAN` also gives the same error.

`Select 1` runs OK. `Begin`, `Begin Tran` or `Begin Transaction` yield error.

I was pondering if someone could have altered the system catalogs so that the reserved word `BEGIN` was replaced by another word. In this case, how would I query for the new equivalent?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `COMMIT` is a shorthand for `COMMIT WORK`, but for all I know that means the same as `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. The latter accepts an optional name, the former doesn't – that seems to be the only the difference between the two. Both variations are (were) supported by SQL Server 7, according to [this](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_Sql_Server_7&seqNum=174).

Comment: The link, which is no longer working, was referencing an online version of book [*Sams Teach Yourself Microsoft SQL Server 7 in 21 Days*](https://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-Microsoft-Server/dp/0672312905), specifically section *Transactions* of chapter *Day 16. Programming SQL Server 7.0*. I can't find any other online versions of it and the Wayback Machine fails me too. (It lets you reach the [chapter header page](https://web.archive.org/web/20151112072156/http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_Sql_Server_7&seqNum=171) but not the section where `COMMIT WORK` is mentioned.)